# Webpack 2 CommonsChunkPlugin not minified

Tags: webpack, webpack-2, chunks

I am using CommonsChunkPlugin to have my vendors and polyfills files shared with all my modules. I believe I am having an error inside of one those my vendor modules. How can I make sure that my vendors file will not be minified? So, I can debug inside. Thank you very much.

```
  var CommonsChunkPlugin = webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin;

  config.entry = {
    'polyfills': './src/polyfills.ts',
    'vendor': './src/vendor.ts',
    'app': './src/main.ts' // our angular app
  };

  config.output = {
    path: root('dist'),
    publicPath: isProd ? '/wwwroot/' : 'http://localhost:8080/',
    filename: isProd ? 'js/[name].[hash].js' : 'js/[name].js',
    chunkFilename: isProd ? '[id].[hash].chunk.js' : '[id].chunk.js'
  };

  config.plugins.push(
    new CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: ['vendor', 'polyfills']
    })
  );
```

Comment: You could use the sourcemaps for this purpose

Comment: I changed my sorcemaps, but it is not changing anything.
  if (isProd) {
    // config.devtool = 'source-map';
    config.devtool = 'eval-source-map';    
  } else {
    config.devtool = 'eval-source-map';
  }

Comment: @Ematipico do you have other idea?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention that you were using TypeScript!

Look, there's a whole article about React & Webpack here, the official documentation: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/react-&-webpack.html

You can skip the part about react and you can focus only on the source maps thing! You basically are missing the `source-map-loader` and the configuration inside your `tsconfig.json`